# UIImagePickerController and fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo like this. However, at this statement,

```
    cameraUI.mediaTypes  = [kUTTypeImage]
```

it shows error like this:

> fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C

How shall I do? I am now using Xcode 6 beta version 4.

```
func presentCamera()
{
    cameraUI = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraUI.delegate = self
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    cameraUI.mediaTypes  = [kUTTypeImage]
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(cameraUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Edited - I have got error like this.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to import `MobileCoreServices` as `kUTTypeImage` defined in `MobileCoreServices` as `let kUTTypeImage: CFString!`.

So add the framework `MobileCoreServices` and write `import MobileCoreServices` in your `.swift` file.

**Go to `BuildPhase` -> `Link Libraries` -> `+` -> `MobileCoreServices.framework`**

and add  `import MobileCoreServices` in your `.swift` file.

**Edit**: Replace your line with as kUTTypeImage is optional so unwrap it

```
cameraUI.mediaTypes  = [kUTTypeImage!]
```

Comment: yes. I now add framework and import also. But it still show error. How shall I do?

Comment: it is still the same. I have deleted app and clear also.

Comment: Have you write this on top `import MobileCoreServices`

Comment: I have tested on `xcode beta 4` it is working fine without error.Which `xcode` are you using???

Comment: I am also now using Xcode beta 4. Is my code also correct as shown in edited image?

Comment: replace your line with `        cameraUI.mediaTypes  = [kUTTypeImage!]
`